# What is the section '0P' in man page?

Tags: manpage

After reading the `stdbool.h` man page its section number, `0P`, drew my attention.

Does it describe `*.h` files or something like that? I can't find the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Under Linux, at least, the `p` stands for POSIX.

Section `0p` is the header files, `1p` is the commands and `3p` is the functions.

Answer (score 3):

I actually wasn't familiar with "man 0" - kudos to paxdiablo.

These are the standard "man" sections":

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_page#Manual_sections

```
Section Description
------- -----------
1       General commands
2       System calls
3       Library functions, covering in particular the C standard library
4       Special files (usually devices, those found in /dev) and drivers
5       File formats and conventions
6       Games and screensavers
7       Miscellanea
8       System administration commands and daemons
```

These are "additional" sections available on some systems (including, apparently, section "0P" on your system:

```
Section Description
------- -----------
0       C library header files
9       Kernel routines
n       Tcl/Tk keywords
x       The X Window System
```